# How to change size of Icon in Toolbar Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, tabbar

Please tell me how to change size of icon in Toolbar.Because when I put another icons with the same resolution they are too small

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                  Icon="{Binding CurrentIcon}"
                 x:Class="App1.BicyclePageMain"
                 xmlns:control="clr-namespace:App1"
                
                   BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=White, Dark=White}">
 
    </ContentPage>
```

[image]

Comment: Is it a png Icon ?

Comment: yes.it is a png Icon.I work in Adobe XD.If I Change size  icon in Adobe still nothing changes.

Comment: i guess thats not possible todo, as the icon size for tabbed page is fixed, you try to create your own Renderer for Tabbed page which can accept icon size

Comment: Please try the solutions in [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/165702/how-do-i-change-the-size-of-an-image-for-a-toolbaritem).

Comment: I add but it does not help

Comment: Well, I agree that the icon size for tabbed page is fixed. You need to implement a custom toolbar instead.